# Natural spline basis in R

Tags: spline, basis

*Hi all*, I hope you can help me on this problem.
I am using the `ns(...)` command in R to generate a base of natural splines, including

- 1 internal knot
- 2 boundary knots
- Intercept equal to `T`

Let's say as an example, `ns(1:20, knots=9, Boundary.knots=c(1,15), intercept=T)`.
I have some questions that I'm struggling a lot to solve by myself, namely:

1. R returns a basis of 3 polynomials: why 3?
2. What is the equation of the 3 polynomials of this basis?
3. Natural splines provide the constraint that after the boundary knots the extrapolation is linear (which is *not exactly* what I would like for my purpose): how should I instead impose the constraint that the extrapolation is actually **constant** (i.e. **flat**) after my rightmost boundary knot?

Thank you very much for all your help with this, you would help me a lot!

Best, EM

Answer (score 0):

For a natural spline the number of basis is equal to the number of knots.
Useful reference
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/172217/why-are-the-basis-functions-for-natural-cubic-splines-expressed-as-they-are-es

The natural spline constraint is that s''(first knot)=0 and s''(last knot)=0

To enforce s' = 0 as you want - would not be a natural spline

Comment: That is not what we get in R with the `ns()` function. The number of basis functions (i.e., df) for a natural spline seems #knots + 1 if intercept is omitted from the basis (with intercept included we have #knots + 2 basis functions). E.g., try: 
`library("splines")`
`x <- 1:100`
`ns_df1 <- ns(x, df = 1)`
`head(ns_df1, 3)`
`attr(ns_df1, "knots")`
`ns_df2 <- ns(x, df = 2)`
`head(ns_df2, 3)`
`attr(ns_df2, "knots")`
`ns_df3 <- ns(x, df = 3)`
`head(ns_df2, 3)`
`attr(ns_df3, "knots")`
`ns_df6 <- ns(x, df = 6)`
`head(ns_df6, 3)`
`attr(ns_df6, "knots")`